# ClosedXML find last row number

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, closedxml

I'm using ClosedXML with C# to modify an Excel workbook.  I need to find the last row number used but `.RowCount()` counts how many rows are in the worksheet.  So it is returning 1 million rows when there are only a few thousand.  I have tried `LastRowUsed()` but that doesn't return an int and there is no `.row` method for it.  How can I get the last row in an int?

Comment: Daniel, I think you marked the wrong comment as the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use RowsUsed();

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = wb.worksheets.add("data");
    var totalRows = ws.RowsUsed().Count();
```

Comment: And then from there you can figure out which row is the last row.

Comment: Other answers are better.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected when there are hidden rows. [@Raidri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610249/raidri) answer is the perfect answer for this question.

Answer (score 36):

The `LastRowUsed()` function returns a row object. Use

```
worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber()
```

to get the number of the last row used.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use **`.LastRowUsed()`**

More useful stuff from [**`official GitHub repo`**](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Simplifying-your-life):

```
range.FirstCell()
range.FirstCellUsed()
range.FirstColumn()
range.FirstColumnUsed()
range.FirstRow()
range.FirstRowUsed()

range.LastCell()
range.LastCellUsed()
range.LastColumn()
range.LastColumnUsed()
range.LastRow()
range.LastRowUsed()
```

Comment: Just be careful not to use the functions "range.Last..." in a big loop, since they can be slow. Assign the value you need in a variable and use that variable in your loop. As in `IXLCell MyLastCellUsed = ws.LastCellUsed;`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.

This example has the best performance:

```
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(FilePath);
// row count
var rowCount = workbook.Worksheet(1).LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
// column count
var columnCount = workbook.Worksheet(1).LastColumnUsed().ColumnNumber();
```

or

```
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(FilePath);
// row count
var rowCount = workbook.Worksheet(1).RowsUsed().Count();
// column count
var columnCount = workbook.Worksheet(1).ColumnUsed().Count();
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

**I used this code**

```
libro = new XLWorkbook("file.xlsx");
hoja = libro.Worksheet(1);
var primeraCeldaUsada = hoja.FirstCellUsed();
var ultimaCeldaUsada = hoja.LastCellUsed();
var rango = hoja.Range(primeraCeldaUsada.Address, ultimaCeldaUsada.Address);
int ultfila = int.Parse(ultimaCeldaUsada.Address.RowNumber.ToString());
for (int i = 7; i <= ultfila; i++)
    {
    hoja.Cell(i, 3).Value = hoja.Cell(i, 3).Address.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code only answers. Please add some explenation to your code, what it does and why you use this code.

Comment: Recorre la columna "i", desde la fila 7 hasta la ultima celda usada y en cada una agrega la posición en curso.